# Naming convention of regex, lookahead and lookbehind

Tags: regex, naming-conventions, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

Why is it counter intuitive?

`/(?<!\d)\d{8}(?!\d)/`, here `(?<!\d)` comes **first**, but called **lookbehind**, `(?!\d)` **next**, but called **lookahead**. All are counter intuitive.

What's the reason to name it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's counterintuitive because there is no consensus whether time goes from front to back or back to front and you simply has a different mindset.

In English we say "Leave the past **behind**", yet "past" is something that happens "**before**" (fore = front).

Comment: But it's still very odd to name it this way

Answer (score 4):

Because the regex engine consumes characters from start to end. So the "ahead" is towards the end of the string, and the "behind" is towards the start.

```
    ...xyz12345678abc...
behind --->---------- ahead
```

The `(?!\d)` is the assertion that there is a decimal number that comes after the `\d{8}`, so the regex engine needs to check the characters in the direction to the end of the string, i.e. **look-ahead**.

Similar for look-behind.

Comment: Sorry,but this seems doesn't explains away why it has to be like this?

Comment: @user: Because you don't walk backwards. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_running)

Comment: But why regex chooses to walk backwards in this case?Is there some benefit?

Comment: @user: No it does not (yeah we've different mind sets. Never mind.)

Comment: I'm interested in the mind sets.Can you talk more about it? :)

Answer (score 4):

They are named based on what they do, not how you happen to use it in that specific expression.

The lookbehind is looking for a match in the string behind (to the left of) the current position.

The lookahead is looking for a match in the string ahead of (to the right of) the current position.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, really.

```
ab
```

Now read the characters left to right.

`a` is behind `b`;
`b` is ahead of `a`

---

That said, you are right that these kinds of relativism can be confusing. For example, in Aymaran culture, [the future is behind; the past is ahead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aymara_language).